# Saving output using hex adds white spaces?

Tags: c++, hex

I have this code

```
int main()
{
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

string filename = "X64-MK10Game.ini";

fin.open(filename.c_str(),ios::binary);
fin>>noskipws;
fout.open("MODDED.ini");

unsigned char x;

while(fin>>x)
{
    fout<<x;
}

return 0;
}
```

The thing with this code is that the file is something like this:

```
[MAIN]
Options
```

the output I'm getting is

```
[MAIN]

Options
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Which platform? And what is the *exact* content of both the input and output file (in terms of ASCII values)? I bet the output contains the sequence "0x0D 0x0D 0x0A".

Comment: @Angew it does contain 0x20 0x0D 0x0A. Windows - Using CODE::BLOCKS. The content in terms of ASCII code is what's shown in the question above.

Comment: Yup.  You need to open `fout` in binary mode.

Comment: Which platform? Sorry.  Just seen you said:  "Windows".

Comment: @MartinBonner Solved :D THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading `fin` in binary mode, but writing `fout` in text mode.

In binary mode, no reinterpretation of end-of-line characters is done. In text mode on Windows, reading the pair `\r\n` is returned as just the character `\n`, and writing the character `\n` causes `\r\n` to be written to the output stream.

So, since `fin` is opened in binary, you will get hold of the characters `\r` and `\n`. Since `fout` is opened in text, writing `\r` into it produces `\r`, and then writing `\n` into it produces `\r\n`, duplicating the carriage-return character.

The solution is to open `fout` in binary mode as well. And since you're apparently interested in binary I/O, you might want to use the unromatted I/O functions [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) instead of `>>` and `<<` manipulators, which are intended for *formatted* I/O.

Comment: Can you please explain to me read() and write() more? I mean do they handle Byte Values? Because I actually read values in hex then convert them to text, modify them then convert them back to hex and store which is a pain. Edit: NVM I found it (y)